# how to draw image on surfaceview android

Tags: android, image, surfaceview

i want to add image on surfaceview and make it as clickable. I could do it via xml using layout. But i am not able to do it dynamically from code. I even cannot use lockcanvas to draw image on canvas since i set my SurfaceHolder type to SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS.So what i have to do to draw image on surfaceview in my app. Pls guide me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some thing like that

```
public class MSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    public MSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(icon, 10, 10, new Paint());        
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Canvas canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (holder) {
                onDraw(canvas);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: how to set the image at the center of surfaceview nad how to strech it to whole surfaceview

Comment: How to scale the bitmap or fill/streach to cover the entire surfaceView?

Comment: similar question with above?