# draw an android.media.Image to a surface

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have this android application.

It use a `SurfaceView`, from where I get the `Surface` through the `SurfaceHolder`.

It also use `ExoPlayer` to stream videos. However I have instantiated an `ImageReader`, getting its `Surface` and passing to the `ExoPlayer`.

Now, I am in the `ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener#onImageAvailable` and I access the latest `Image`.

I want to manipulate the `Image` and send the new data to the "`SurfaceView`" `Surface`.

How can I "draw" an `android.media.Image` to an `android.view.Surface` ?

Comment: There is code floating around for converting an `Image` obtained from a `MediaProjection` (Android 5.0+ screenshot API) into a `Bitmap`, taking stride into account. Those have only one plane, though. I assume that there is a recipe for doing the same sort of thing for a YUV `Image`.

Comment: Were you able to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear to me. 
The way to get android.media.Image is by the Camera2 API, and there you can provide a surface and the "camera" will draw over it. Please refer to [Camera2Video example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video)

Another way to get the Image object is from ImageReader (while decoding video for example). In this case you want to draw the image, but you can not provide a surface to the ImageReader(there is an internal surface that is not displayed). In this case you can draw the Image on a SurfaceView.
Assuming this is the case, you need to convert an Image to a Bitmap objects.

You have discussion about how perform this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775968/how-to-convert-android-media-image-to-bitmap-object/57842072#57842072)

Answer (score -1):

Possible duplicate of: [how to draw image on surfaceview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912102/how-to-draw-image-on-surfaceview-android)

First get your canvas by using `lockCanvas()` (see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#lockCanvas%28%29)), second get your image and make it a drawable using:

```
my_bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
  MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri),
  0,0,90, 90);
drawable=new BitmapDrawable(my_bitmap);
```

After that you can draw the drawable to the locked canvas and use `unlockCanvasAndPost (Canvas canvas)` to post the updated canvas back to the surfaceview.

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand: how can I use Bitmap.createBitmap to convert a android.media.Image instance? I'm not talking about an image resource...

Comment: How did you get the media image? It should have a uri that points to the actual data.

Comment: Take a look at the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673127/android-imagereader-acquirelatestimage-returns-invalid-jpg this is how you can get the bitmap out of the image object.

Comment: I have the image from an ImageReader attached to a MediaCodec

Comment: Yes I understand now, could the answer in my comment above help you further?

Comment: the problem is the android.media.Image is NOT a simple jpeg / png. It's a full YUV, where each of the planes and the strides are used.

Comment: You should specify that clearly in your question, I am not sure how to help you with the YUV, sorry.