# How to make CameraX Preview freeze when take a photo?

Tags: kotlin, android-camerax

I have a flow with my custom CameraX like this:

- Open camera preview (live)
- Click button to take a photo
- Have a process when clicking that button (convert the path to bitmap, rotated the image, cropping the image automatically, save into device)
- After running all the process and successfully, send the image to other Fragment and display it into a glide

The question is when `running all the process (in step 3)` have a `delayed 2 seconds` and the camera preview still `live` (`not freeze` or `lock`). How to make `camera preview freeze or lock when running the process`?

This is my code to running camera preview in Camera X:

```
class CameraFragment : Fragment() {

        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false)
        }

        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

            viewFinder.post { setupCamera() }
        }

        private fun setupCamera() {
            CameraX.unbindAll()
            CameraX.bindToLifecycle(
                this,
                buildPreviewUseCase(),
                buildImageCaptureUseCase()
            )
        }

        private fun buildPreviewUseCase(): Preview {
            val preview = Preview(
                UseCaseConfigBuilder.buildPreviewConfig(
                    viewFinder.display
                )
            )
            preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener { previewOutput ->
                updateViewFinderWithPreview(previewOutput)
                correctPreviewOutputForDisplay(previewOutput.textureSize)
            }
            return preview
        }

        private fun buildImageCaptureUseCase(): ImageCapture {
            val capture = ImageCapture(
                UseCaseConfigBuilder.buildImageCaptureConfig(
                    viewFinder.display
                )
            )
            cameraCaptureImageButton.setOnClickListener {
                capture.takePicture(
                    FileCreator.createTempFile(JPEG_FORMAT),
                    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),
                    object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener {
                        override fun onImageSaved(file: File) {
                            // I want make a freeze camera preview when execute this before launch *launchGalleryFragment(path)*
                            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath)
                            val rotatedBitmap = bitmap.rotate(90)
                            val croppedImage = cropImage(rotatedBitmap, viewFinder, rectangle)
                            val path = saveImage(croppedImage)
                            requireActivity().runOnUiThread {
                                launchGalleryFragment(path)
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onError(
                            imageCaptureError: ImageCapture.ImageCaptureError,
                            message: String,
                            cause: Throwable?
                        ) {
                            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Error: $message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show()
                            Log.e("CameraFragment", "Capture error $imageCaptureError: $message", cause)
                        }
                    })
            }
            return capture
        }

        private fun launchGalleryFragment(path: String) {
            val action = CameraFragmentDirections.actionLaunchGalleryFragment(path)
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you can try to unbind the preview use case :

version 1.0.0-alpha06: `CameraX.unbind(preview);`

version > 1.0.0-alpha07: `cameraProvider.unbind(preview);`

In your case, you need to save the preview use case into a variable to then unbind it:

```
// Declare the preview use case variable (as in the CameraXBasic example)
private var preview: Preview? = null
```

Then instantiate the variable (like you did):

```
private fun buildPreviewUseCase(): Preview {
    preview = Preview(
        UseCaseConfigBuilder.buildPreviewConfig(
            viewFinder.display
        )
    )
    preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener { previewOutput ->
        updateViewFinderWithPreview(previewOutput)
        correctPreviewOutputForDisplay(previewOutput.textureSize)
    }
    return preview
}
```

Then, when you want to freeze the preview just unbind the use case:

```
CameraX.unbind(preview);
```

**EDIT**
As @Billda said in this post : [CameraX - crash when unbinding Preview UseCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60751780/camerax-crash-when-unbinding-preview-usecase?noredirect=1&lq=1) :

> To freeze a preview you should not unbind Preview usecase. There may
>   API for that in the future, but currently the recommended way is to
>   store latest frame from ImageAnalysis and put it to ImageView
>   overlapping the preview.

So I decided to update my answer to give another solution implementing an analyser with ImageAnalysis (1.0.0-beta02).

1- Create the FreezeAnalyzer class:

```
class FreezeAnalyzer(private val callback: FreezeCallback) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
    private var flag = false

    override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
        if(flag){
            flag = false
            val bitmap = toBitmap(image)
            callback.onLastFrameCaptured(bitmap)
        }
        image.close()
    }

    fun freeze(){
        flag = true
    }

    private fun toBitmap(image: ImageProxy): Bitmap {
        // Convert the imageProxy to Bitmap
        // ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56772967/converting-imageproxy-to-bitmap
        // ISSUE, on my android 7 when converting the imageProxy to Bitmap I have a problem with the colors...
        var bitmap = ...

        // Rotate the bitmap
        val rotationDegrees = image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees.toFloat()
        if (rotationDegrees != 0f) {
            val matrix = Matrix()
            matrix.postRotate(rotationDegrees)
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height, matrix, true)
        }
        return bitmap
    }
}
```

2- XML

```
<androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
    android:id="@+id/preview_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

3- Initialize the imageAnalyser

```
val resolutionSize = Size(preview_view.width, preview_view.height)

// Set up analyser
imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder().apply {
    setTargetResolution(resolutionSize)
    setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
}.build()

val analyzer = FreezeAnalyzer(object : FreezeCallback {
    override fun onLastFrameCaptured(bitmap: Bitmap) {
        runOnUiThread {
            preview_view.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            image_view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        }
    }
})
imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(executor, analyzer)
```

4- Bind the imageAnalysis use case

```
try {
    val camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
        this,
        cameraSelector,
        preview,
        imageAnalysis,
        imageCapture
    )
    preview.setSurfaceProvider(preview_view.createSurfaceProvider(camera.cameraInfo))
}
```

5- Capture the picture

```
btn_capture.setOnClickListener {
    file = File(externalMediaDirs.first(), "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg")
    val outputFileOptions: ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions =
        ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(file!!).build()
    analyzer.freeze()
    imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions, executor, onImageSavedCallback)
}
```

6- Release

```
btn_release.setOnClickListener {
    preview_view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    image_view.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}
```

I hope it helps, I'm not an expert so if you have some improvements you are welcome !

Comment: what code in the `preview` ? can you give me full source code?

Comment: Where I add `CameraX.unbind(preview)` function? I try inside `onImageSaved()` it's forclose

Comment: Yes inside the `onImageSaved()`, I tested it with the CameraXBasic example and it works. I think it comes from your executor, can you try to do as in the CameraXBasic example using `ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext())`

Comment: Yeah, it's work after I add that into my code. But, why not freeze immediately after I click the camera button? There is still a delay before immediately freeze.

Comment: Well I think there is a delay between the moment you click on the button and the moment the callback is called (time for the camera to take the picture).Try to unbind the preview in the `onClickListener`, just after calling `capture.takePicture()`. Nevertheless, the freezed preview can be different to the photo taken.

Comment: Ahh I see, it's not good to unbind the preview in the `onClickListener` after calling `capture.takePicture()`. But how if I handle a delay between the moment I click on the button and the moment the callback is called (time for the camera to take the picture). It's possible?

Comment: The last thing that comes to me is to add a delay as in the cameraXBasic example:         `container.postDelayed({CameraX.unbind(preview)}, 150L)`. Good luck.

Comment: @LaurentP22 Just one question that I'm curious about since `imageAnalyzer` is returning bitmap in `FreezeCallback` why add `ImageCapture` use case, the bitmap can be processed in the background thread (Cropped and saved to a file)

Comment: Well depending on the situation I imagine there is no problem to remove the `ImageCapture` use case and then process the bitmap as you said. However there are some advantages using the `ImageCapture` use case: When taking a picture with the `ImageCapture` use case some information are saved with the photo (device model, focal length…). Moreover the quality of the picture might be better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to use it, but my Android Studio can't recognize `FreezeCallback`. Do I need some non-standard dependency?

Comment: maybe use `ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback.onImageSaved(ImageCapture.OutputFileResults)`
outputFileResults.getSavedUri to ImageView.setImageURI(Uri).
one step is save;
two step is read;