# CameraX - crash when unbinding Preview UseCase

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-camerax

I need to freeze (stop) the preview when user initiates taking the photo. I've searched around and I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59661727/how-to-make-camerax-preview-freeze-when-take-a-photo) SO post that mentions unbinding Preview UseCase. I've tried that and at first it works correctly on Android 9+, but on lower Android I receive following error in Logcat and picture is not taken.

```
ImageCapture: takePictureInternal onFailure

androidx.camera.core.ImageCaptureException: The completer object was garbage collected - this future would otherwise never complete. The tag was: FutureChain[androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.futures.ChainingListenableFuture@3ee79178]
        at androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture$ImageCaptureRequest.lambda$notifyCallbackError$1$ImageCapture$ImageCaptureRequest(ImageCapture.java:1911)
        at androidx.camera.core.-$$Lambda$ImageCapture$ImageCaptureRequest$1G7WSvt8TANxhZtOyewefm68pg4.run(lambda)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter$FutureGarbageCollectedException: The completer object was garbage collected - this future would otherwise never complete. The tag was: FutureChain[androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.futures.ChainingListenableFuture@3ee79178]
```

And also a lot of logs starts to appear like

```
gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_lock usage mismatch usage=0x30 cb->usage=0x3
```

My suspicion is that the way how I retrieve `ProcessCameraProvider` instance is wrong - I just store it once I get from the Future returned from `getInstance` method and use it later. But when I tried getting the future again it did not helped. I've found no workaround around this and I am considering replacing CameraX with some other Camera library because I've spent too many time on that but maybe someone has some answer.

I've created a [demo project](https://github.com/davidbilik/camerax-crash-sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bilikdavid/cameraxsample/MainActivity.kt) where I test this weird behavior so you can take a look at the full code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've posted this as a bug to [Google Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153891428) and this error is intended behavior. To freeze a preview you should not unbind Preview usecase. There may API for that in the future, but currently the recommended way is to store latest frame from `ImageAnalysis` and put it to ImageView overlapping the preview.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the solution that I posted in the other post doesn't work with old phones. I tested it on an android 7 and I had the following error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraX-camerax_io_0
>       Process: com.hermosodev.camerax, PID: 23735
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Image is already closed
>           at android.media.Image.throwISEIfImageIsInvalid(Image.java:68)
>           at android.media.ImageReader$SurfaceImage.getFormat(ImageReader.java:679)
>           at androidx.camera.core.AndroidImageProxy.getFormat(AndroidImageProxy.java:78)
>           at androidx.camera.core.ForwardingImageProxy.getFormat(ForwardingImageProxy.java:75)
>           at androidx.camera.core.ForwardingImageProxy.getFormat(ForwardingImageProxy.java:75)
>           at androidx.camera.core.ForwardingImageProxy.getFormat(ForwardingImageProxy.java:75)
>           at androidx.camera.core.ImageUtil.imageToJpegByteArray(ImageUtil.java:51)
>           at androidx.camera.core.ImageSaver.run(ImageSaver.java:95)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

With my android 7 when I'm capturing a picture the preview is automatically freezed for a short time before being released (which could explain my error).

What about freezing the preview in the `OnImageSavedCallback` ?

```
runOnUiThread {
   cameraProvider.unbind(previewUseCase)
}
```

Comment: According to Google developers unbinding is not correct way to freeze preview - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153891428