# CameraX Image take picture slow

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax

I am using CameraX

Here is my image capture :

```
 mImageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
            .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
            .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
            .build()
```

ImageCaptureListener :

```
mImageCapture.takePicture(
                executor!!,
                object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {


                    override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
                        Log.d("AAAA", "Success")

                            val rotatedBitmap = bitmapHelper.rotateImage(
                                bitmapHelper.imageToBitmap(image = image.image!!),
                                image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees.toFloat()
                            )

                            runOnUiThread {
                                mImageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap)
                            }

                    }

                    override fun onError(
                        imageCaptureError: Int,
                        message: String,
                        cause: Throwable?
                    ) {
                        2
                        super.onError(imageCaptureError, message, cause)
                    }
                })
```

When i call `takePicture` app freezes, and only after 3-4 seconds onCaptureSuccess called

How can I make this process faster?

Comment: I think you need call `image.close()`. Try it, before `runOnUiThread`

Comment: Hey @Rasul did you ever able to find out why it was slow. I mean I don't have anything like file operations and still only cameraX is taking about 1.5 seconds

Comment: Hello Rasul Agakishiyev, have you found solution for this problem? Could you share it to me or people in need?

Comment: I think that in your case rotating the bitmap is causing the delay

Answer (score 1):

I was comparing this solution with the freeze view solution described in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56772967/converting-imageproxy-to-bitmap) and the second one is faster than getting the image with `OnImageCapturedCallback`. This is an example of how to freeze the screen and show the `ImageProxy` using `ImageAnalysis`, check the following example [github](https://github.com/camroga/camera-x)

Comment: Nice idea but not works. This is your code result: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/9253378/207067746-5ef15e4d-5b80-4b91-8ad0-e1f3dca27e6b.png

Comment: I checked the repository. I ran the app which works in a Samsung Galaxy A21 s [GIF](https://github.com/camroga/camera-x/blob/master/gif/camera-x.gif). @BinhHo can you add more details in order to solve this issue?

Comment: This issue related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56772967/converting-imageproxy-to-bitmap

Comment: And using this to resolve the issue: https://github.com/alexcohn/camera-samples/blob/f3b797736153c6e0d03cf05e497677dfd168e765/CameraXTfLite/utils/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera/utils/YuvToRgbConverter.kt#L100

Answer (score 1):

CameraX take photo slow because of compressing into JPEG.

The difference between `MINIMIZE_LATENCY_MODE` and `MAXIMIZE_QUALITY_MODE` is the JPEG image compression quality.

```
  private static final byte JPEG_QUALITY_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY_MODE = 100;
  private static final byte JPEG_QUALITY_MINIMIZE_LATENCY_MODE = 95;
```

Therefore, even if the `MINIMIZE_LATENCY_MODE` mode is set, the image quality will only decrease from 100 to 95. Not much difference.

From the [Version 1.1.0-alpha11](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera#1.1.0-alpha11), the API provides an additional function `setJpegQuality` that allows to customize the compression quality. Can improve the delay when taking pictures.

If you don't care about the best image quality, you can use this method.

```
 imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
            .setJpegQuality(QUALITY_JPEG_75)
            .build()
```

Answer (score -1):

You no need to use ImageAnalysis `usecase` because `CameraX` already supported get bitmap from `previewView`

See more detail here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView#getBitmap()