# Converting a captured image to a Bitmap

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception, android-bitmap, android-camerax

I'm exploring CameraX API of android using Java and trying to build capture image use-case.
Here is the code for

```
private void takePicture() {
        imageCapture.takePicture(new ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCaptureSuccess(ImageProxy image, int rotationDegrees) {
                Bitmap bitmap = rotateImage(toBitmap(image.getImage()), (float) rotationDegrees);
                ImageView takenImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                super.onCaptureSuccess(image, rotationDegrees);
            }
        });
    }
```

and to convert the image captured to bitmap. I'm trying to implement @Ahwar's answer in the following question which is written in Java: [Converting ImageProxy to Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56772967/converting-imageproxy-to-bitmap)
Here is the code answer given there:

```
private Bitmap toBitmap(Image image) {
        Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
        ByteBuffer yBuffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
        ByteBuffer uBuffer = planes[1].getBuffer();
        ByteBuffer vBuffer = planes[2].getBuffer();

        int ySize = yBuffer.remaining();
        int uSize = uBuffer.remaining();
        int vSize = vBuffer.remaining();

        byte[] nv21 = new byte[ySize + uSize + vSize];
        //U and V are swapped
        yBuffer.get(nv21, 0, ySize);
        vBuffer.get(nv21, ySize, vSize);
        uBuffer.get(nv21, ySize + vSize, uSize);

        YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(nv21, ImageFormat.NV21, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, yuvImage.getWidth(), yuvImage.getHeight()), 75, out);

        byte[] imageBytes = out.toByteArray();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
    }
```

***My issue***: 
When I call toBitmap(image) function, I'm getting **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**, and after debugging, I understood that size of image planes is ***just 1 rather than 3***.
I have attached exception received here,

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.camerax3, PID: 17342
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
        at com.example.camerax3.activity.MainActivity.toBitmap(MainActivity.java:210)
        at com.example.camerax3.activity.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:45)
        at com.example.camerax3.activity.MainActivity$2.onCaptureSuccess(MainActivity.java:239)
        at androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture$ImageCaptureRequest.dispatchImage(ImageCapture.java:1341)
        at androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture$10.onImageAvailable(ImageCapture.java:657)
        at androidx.camera.core.MetadataImageReader$3.run(MetadataImageReader.java:279)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7099)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Could anyone suggest a way to solve this ?. I have read many answers in Kotlin but I'm trying to implement the same in **Java**. 
Any alternative method to convert image to bitmap in java is appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code worked for me, try it.

```
  private Bitmap getBitmap(ImageProxy image) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        buffer.rewind();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
        byte[] clonedBytes = bytes.clone();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(clonedBytes, 0, clonedBytes.length);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Extension to get a bitmap from `ImageProxy`

In Kotlin:

```
fun Image.toBitmap(): Bitmap {
    val buffer = planes[0].buffer
    buffer.rewind()
    val bytes = ByteArray(buffer.capacity())
    buffer.get(bytes)
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
}
```

And set like this in Kotlin:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(image.image?.toBitmap())
```

And set like this in Java:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(YourExtensionHelper.toBitmap(image.getImage()));
```