# Android: How to get raw image data from camera

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, arcore

Currently, I am planning on doing an app utilizing RAW data provided by the camera in Android devices (pixel 2).

And I use ARCore to get frame data as following:

```
final Frame frame = session.update();
final Camera camera = frame.getCamera();
Image image = frame.acquireCameraImage();
```

It seems not a raw data I want.

How can I get raw image data by ARCore?
Or is there other way to do that?

---

I have get the bitmap before.
But it is not raw image.
What I mean the "raw" is the original data (RGB RAW DATA) form CMOS without any process, like Gamma correction, AWB, AE, or any pose process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert android Image object to byte array

```
Image image = null;
try {
    image = frame.acquireCameraImage();
} catch (NotYetAvailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

int h = image.getHeight();
int w = image.getWidth();
Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
int pixelSizeBits = ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888);
byte[] yuvByteArray = new byte[(int)((h * w) * pixelSizeBits / 8)];
YuvToByteArray yuvToByteArray = new YuvToByteArray();
yuvToByteArray.setPixelCount(h * w);
yuvToByteArray.imageToByteArray(image, yuvByteArray);
image.close();
```

YuvToByteArray.kt

```
/*
 * Copyright 2020 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.memex.Helper

import android.graphics.ImageFormat
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.media.Image

class YuvToByteArray {

    var pixelCount: Int = -1

    fun imageToByteArray(image: Image, outputBuffer: ByteArray) {
        assert(image.format == ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)

        val imageCrop = Rect(0, 0, image.width, image.height)
        val imagePlanes = image.planes

        imagePlanes.forEachIndexed { planeIndex, plane ->
            // How many values are read in input for each output value written
            // Only the Y plane has a value for every pixel, U and V have half the resolution i.e.
            //
            // Y Plane            U Plane    V Plane
            // ===============    =======    =======
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y    U U U U    V V V V
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y    U U U U    V V V V
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y    U U U U    V V V V
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y    U U U U    V V V V
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
            val outputStride: Int

            // The index in the output buffer the next value will be written at
            // For Y it's zero, for U and V we start at the end of Y and interleave them i.e.
            //
            // First chunk        Second chunk
            // ===============    ===============
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y    V U V U V U V U
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y    V U V U V U V U
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y    V U V U V U V U
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y    V U V U V U V U
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
            var outputOffset: Int

            when (planeIndex) {
                0 -> {
                    outputStride = 1
                    outputOffset = 0
                }
                1 -> {
                    outputStride = 2
                    // For NV21 format, U is in odd-numbered indices
                    outputOffset = pixelCount + 1
                }
                2 -> {
                    outputStride = 2
                    // For NV21 format, V is in even-numbered indices
                    outputOffset = pixelCount
                }
                else -> {
                    // Image contains more than 3 planes, something strange is going on
                    return@forEachIndexed
                }
            }

            val planeBuffer = plane.buffer
            val rowStride = plane.rowStride
            val pixelStride = plane.pixelStride

            // We have to divide the width and height by two if it's not the Y plane
            val planeCrop = if (planeIndex == 0) {
                imageCrop
            } else {
                Rect(
                    imageCrop.left / 2,
                    imageCrop.top / 2,
                    imageCrop.right / 2,
                    imageCrop.bottom / 2
                )
            }

            val planeWidth = planeCrop.width()
            val planeHeight = planeCrop.height()

            // Intermediate buffer used to store the bytes of each row
            val rowBuffer = ByteArray(plane.rowStride)

            // Size of each row in bytes
            val rowLength = if (pixelStride == 1 && outputStride == 1) {
                planeWidth
            } else {
                // Take into account that the stride may include data from pixels other than this
                // particular plane and row, and that could be between pixels and not after every
                // pixel:
                //
                // |---- Pixel stride ----|                    Row ends here --> |
                // | Pixel 1 | Other Data | Pixel 2 | Other Data | ... | Pixel N |
                //
                // We need to get (N-1) * (pixel stride bytes) per row + 1 byte for the last pixel
                (planeWidth - 1) * pixelStride + 1
            }

            for (row in 0 until planeHeight) {
                // Move buffer position to the beginning of this row
                planeBuffer.position(
                    (row + planeCrop.top) * rowStride + planeCrop.left * pixelStride
                )

                if (pixelStride == 1 && outputStride == 1) {
                    // When there is a single stride value for pixel and output, we can just copy
                    // the entire row in a single step
                    planeBuffer.get(outputBuffer, outputOffset, rowLength)
                    outputOffset += rowLength
                } else {
                    // When either pixel or output have a stride > 1 we must copy pixel by pixel
                    planeBuffer.get(rowBuffer, 0, rowLength)
                    for (col in 0 until planeWidth) {
                        outputBuffer[outputOffset] = rowBuffer[col * pixelStride]
                        outputOffset += outputStride
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

function to get ARGB bitmap from yuv byte array:

```
public Bitmap createImageBitmap(byte[] bytes, Bitmap outputBitmap,
                                    RenderScript renderScript,
                                    ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB intrinsicYuvToRGB, Type typeYUV) {
        Allocation inputAllocation = Allocation.createSized(renderScript,
                typeYUV.getElement(), bytes.length);
        Allocation outputAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, outputBitmap);
        inputAllocation.copyFrom(bytes);
        intrinsicYuvToRGB.setInput(inputAllocation);
        intrinsicYuvToRGB.forEach(outputAllocation);
        outputAllocation.copyTo(outputBitmap);
        return outputBitmap;
    }
```

How to use this:

```
// yuvByteArray and outputBitmap from the first code segment
// renderScript, intrinsicYuvToRGB, and typeYUV are provided here: https://github.com/android/renderscript-intrinsics-replacement-toolkit
Bitmap rgbBitmap = createImageBitmap(yuvByteArray, outputBitmap, renderScript, intrinsicYuvToRGB, typeYUV);
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to get the bitmap for a camera image, there are multiple ways you can do this and you do not need to use ARCore.

For example you can use the standard CameraX solution to get a BitMap when you capture an image - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63823500/334402

You could also use OpenCV which might be good if you plan to do any image analysis. Just be aware it can be a little tricky to include in a project and much of the documentation still refers to Eclipse rather than Android studio at the time of writing.