# What is the difference between an ImageView and ImageProxy in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I am new to android studio and wondered if anyone could clear this up for me. Many thanks.

Comment: There is nothing in your question related to Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView) is actually a [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View), that:

> Displays image resources, for example, a Bitmap or Drawable resources. ImageView is also commonly used to [apply tints to an image](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageTintMode(android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode)) and handle [image scaling](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setScaleType(android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType)).

While [ImageProxy](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageProxy):

> An image proxy which has a similar interface as [Image](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image.html).

Besides that, there is another interface named [PlaneProxy](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageProxy.PlaneProxy), which is a:

> A plane proxy which has an analogous interface as [Image.Plane](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image.Plane.html).

There are two quite different concepts. An [ImageProxy can be converted to a Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56772967/converting-imageproxy-to-bitmap), as it ca be captured from the camera.