# How to convert ImageProxy to Btimap correctly?

Tags: java, android, camera

I've checked all sulutions described in [Converting ImageProxy to Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56772967/converting-imageproxy-to-bitmap) and the only one that works in many devices is the java version of [this class](https://github.com/xizhang/camerax-gpuimage/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/appinmotion/gpuimage/YuvToRgbConverter.kt), so I'm using the class below to convert an ImageProxy to a Bitmap:

```
public class YuvToRgbConverter {

    private RenderScript rs;
    private ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB scriptYuvToRgb;
    private int pixelCount = -1;
    private byte[] yuvBuffer = null;
    private Allocation inputAllocation = null;
    private Allocation outputAllocation = null;

    public YuvToRgbConverter(Context context) {
        rs = RenderScript.create(context);
        scriptYuvToRgb = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    }

    @Synchronized
    public void yuvToRgb(Image image, Bitmap output) {
        // Ensure that the intermediate output byte buffer is allocated
        if (yuvBuffer == null) {
            pixelCount = image.getCropRect().width() * image.getCropRect().height();
            // Bits per pixel is an average for the whole image, so it's useful to compute the size
            // of the full buffer but should not be used to determine pixel offsets
            int pixelSizeBits = ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888);
            yuvBuffer = new byte[pixelCount * pixelSizeBits / 8];
        }

        // Get the YUV data in byte array form using NV21 format
        imageToByteArray(image, yuvBuffer);

        // Ensure that the RenderScript inputs and outputs are allocated
        if (inputAllocation == null) {
            // Explicitly create an element with type NV21, since that's the pixel format we use
            Type elemType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.YUV(rs)).setYuvFormat(ImageFormat.NV21).create();
            inputAllocation = Allocation.createSized(rs, elemType.getElement(), yuvBuffer.length);
        }
        if (outputAllocation == null) {
            outputAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, output);
        }

        // Convert NV21 format YUV to RGB
        inputAllocation.copyFrom(yuvBuffer);
        scriptYuvToRgb.setInput(inputAllocation);
        scriptYuvToRgb.forEach(outputAllocation);
        outputAllocation.copyTo(output);
    }


    private void imageToByteArray(Image image, byte[] outputBuffer) {
        assert (image.getFormat() == ImageFormat.YUV_420_888);

        Rect imageCrop = image.getCropRect();
        Image.Plane[] imagePlanes = image.getPlanes();

        for (int planeIndex = 0; planeIndex < imagePlanes.length; ++planeIndex) {
            Image.Plane plane = imagePlanes[planeIndex];
            int outputStride = 0;
            int outputOffset = 0;
            switch (planeIndex) {
                case 0:
                    outputStride = 1;
                    outputOffset = 0;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    outputStride = 2;
                    outputOffset = pixelCount + 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    outputStride = 2;
                    outputOffset = pixelCount;
                    break;
                default:
                    return;

            }

            ByteBuffer planeBuffer = plane.getBuffer();
            int rowStride = plane.getRowStride();
            int pixelStride = plane.getPixelStride();
            Rect planeCrop = imageCrop;
            if (planeIndex != 0) {
                planeCrop = new Rect(imageCrop.left / 2, imageCrop.top / 2, imageCrop.right / 2, imageCrop.bottom / 2);
            }

            int planeWidth = planeCrop.width();
            int planeHeight = planeCrop.height();

            byte[] rowBuffer = new byte[plane.getRowStride()];

            int rowLength = planeWidth;
            if (pixelStride != 1 || outputStride != 1) {
                rowLength = (planeWidth - 1) * pixelStride + 1;
            }
            for (int row = 0; row < planeHeight; row++) {
                planeBuffer.position((row + planeCrop.top) * rowStride + planeCrop.left * pixelStride);
                if (pixelStride == 1 && outputStride == 1) {
                    planeBuffer.get(outputBuffer, outputOffset, rowLength);
                    outputOffset += rowLength;
                } else {
                    planeBuffer.get(rowBuffer, 0, rowLength);
                    for (int col = 0; col < planeWidth; col++) {
                        outputBuffer[outputOffset] = rowBuffer[col * pixelStride];
                        outputOffset += outputStride;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This class works as expected in many devices but in some devices I get a green bitmap.

**Correct conversion in many devices**

[image]

**Green bitmap in some devices**

[image]

So my question is how can I fix this problem? Is there any better way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Here**, you can easily convert Imageproxy to bitmap.

```
private static ByteBuffer yuv420ThreePlanesToNV21(
          Plane[] yuv420888planes, int width, int height) {
    int imageSize = width * height;
    byte[] out = new byte[imageSize + 2 * (imageSize / 4)];

    if (areUVPlanesNV21(yuv420888planes, width, height)) {
      // Copy the Y values.
      yuv420888planes[0].getBuffer().get(out, 0, imageSize);

      ByteBuffer uBuffer = yuv420888planes[1].getBuffer();
      ByteBuffer vBuffer = yuv420888planes[2].getBuffer();
      // Get the first V value from the V buffer, since the U buffer does not contain it.
      vBuffer.get(out, imageSize, 1);
      // Copy the first U value and the remaining VU values from the U buffer.
      uBuffer.get(out, imageSize + 1, 2 * imageSize / 4 - 1);
    } else {
      // Fallback to copying the UV values one by one, which is slower but also works.
      // Unpack Y.
      unpackPlane(yuv420888planes[0], width, height, out, 0, 1);
      // Unpack U.
      unpackPlane(yuv420888planes[1], width, height, out, imageSize + 1, 2);
      // Unpack V.
      unpackPlane(yuv420888planes[2], width, height, out, imageSize, 2);
    }

    return ByteBuffer.wrap(out);
  }




 /** Checks if the UV plane buffers of a YUV_420_888 image are in the NV21 format. */
  @RequiresApi(VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
  private static boolean areUVPlanesNV21(Plane[] planes, int width, int height) {
    int imageSize = width * height;

    ByteBuffer uBuffer = planes[1].getBuffer();
    ByteBuffer vBuffer = planes[2].getBuffer();

    // Backup buffer properties.
    int vBufferPosition = vBuffer.position();
    int uBufferLimit = uBuffer.limit();

    // Advance the V buffer by 1 byte, since the U buffer will not contain the first V value.
    vBuffer.position(vBufferPosition + 1);
    // Chop off the last byte of the U buffer, since the V buffer will not contain the last U value.
    uBuffer.limit(uBufferLimit - 1);

    // Check that the buffers are equal and have the expected number of elements.
    boolean areNV21 =
            (vBuffer.remaining() == (2 * imageSize / 4 - 2)) && (vBuffer.compareTo(uBuffer) == 0);

    // Restore buffers to their initial state.
    vBuffer.position(vBufferPosition);
    uBuffer.limit(uBufferLimit);

    return areNV21;
  }



/**
   * Unpack an image plane into a byte array.
   *
   * <p>The input plane data will be copied in 'out', starting at 'offset' and every pixel will be
   * spaced by 'pixelStride'. Note that there is no row padding on the output.
   */
  @TargetApi(VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
  private static void unpackPlane(
          Plane plane, int width, int height, byte[] out, int offset, int pixelStride) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = plane.getBuffer();
    buffer.rewind();

    // Compute the size of the current plane.
    // We assume that it has the aspect ratio as the original image.
    int numRow = (buffer.limit() + plane.getRowStride() - 1) / plane.getRowStride();
    if (numRow == 0) {
      return;
    }
    int scaleFactor = height / numRow;
    int numCol = width / scaleFactor;

    // Extract the data in the output buffer.
    int outputPos = offset;
    int rowStart = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < numRow; row++) {
      int inputPos = rowStart;
      for (int col = 0; col < numCol; col++) {
        out[outputPos] = buffer.get(inputPos);
        outputPos += pixelStride;
        inputPos += plane.getPixelStride();
      }
      rowStart += plane.getRowStride();
    }
  }

public static Bitmap getBitmap(ByteBuffer data, FrameMetadata metadata) {
    data.rewind();
    byte[] imageInBuffer = new byte[data.limit()];
    data.get(imageInBuffer, 0, imageInBuffer.length);
    try {
      YuvImage image =
              new YuvImage(
                      imageInBuffer, ImageFormat.NV21, metadata.getWidth(), metadata.getHeight(), null);
      ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      image.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, metadata.getWidth(), metadata.getHeight()), 50, stream);


      /*image.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, metadata.getWidth(), metadata.getHeight()), 100, stream);
      byte[] jpegByteArray = stream.toByteArray();
      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegByteArray, 0, jpegByteArray.length);
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

      Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(),true));
      Paint p = new Paint();
      p.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0); // ARGB for the color, in this case red
      p.setAlpha(0);
      p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
      c.drawPaint(p);*/

      Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(stream.toByteArray(), 0, stream.size());

      stream.close();
      return bmp;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("VisionProcessorBase", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
  }
```

**How to use**

```
    public void processImageProxy(ImageProxy image) {
    

 FrameMetadata frameMetadata =
            new FrameMetadata.Builder()
                    .setWidth(image.getWidth())
                    .setHeight(image.getHeight())
                    .setRotation(image.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees())
                    .build();    


     ByteBuffer nv21Buffer =
                yuv420ThreePlanesToNV21(Objects.requireNonNull(image.getImage()).getPlanes(), image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        Bitmap yourBitmap = getBitmap(nv21Buffer, frameMetadata);
    
    }
```

Comment: I've used this solution too but the result is the same, I mean green bitmap in some devices.

Comment: will you tell me, which device has a green bitmap?