# How to draw a bitmap to a SurfaceView?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, surfaceview, android-bitmap

I am trying to draw a bitmap to my `SurfaceView` actually with the following code: (this will be run in another `Thread` and in a `while`, because it needs to refresh the `SurfaceView`).

```
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                // Enable drawing
                // ERROR LINE!
                Canvas ca = mPreview2.Holder.LockCanvas();

                // Get current frame
                Bitmap test = mediaPlayer.CurrentFrame;

                // Actual drawing
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                ca.DrawBitmap(test, 0, 0, paint);   

                // Stop drawing
                mPreview2.Holder.UnlockCanvasAndPost(ca);
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

But I've got the following error: (this is happening on line: `Canvas ca = mPreview2.Holder.LockCanvas();`

```
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: You should show the full exception trace in your question.

Comment: ttry this answer on stack overflow...http://stackoverflow.com/a/12912187/3678308

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now I can draw a bitmap, but I have still one problem!

Because the quality of the right screen is really bad (see image):

[image]

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**

What I did is using a `MemoryStream` which compress the `Bitmap` to .JPG with a quality of 100 and decode the `byte` `array` to a `Bitmap`. It works great now! See code below:

```
   private void DrawCanvas()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Canvas canvas = holder2.LockCanvas();

                if (canvas != null)
                {
                    Bitmap currentBitmap = mediaPlayer.CurrentFrame;

                    if(currentBitmap != null)
                    {
                        Paint paint = new Paint();

                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

                        currentBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, ms);

                        byte[] bitmapData = ms.ToArray();

                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(bitmapData, 0, bitmapData.Length);

                        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, mPreview2.Width, mPreview2.Height, true);

                        canvas.DrawBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, paint);

                        bitmap.Recycle();
                        scaledBitmap.Recycle();
                        currentBitmap.Recycle();
                    }
                    holder2.UnlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
```