# Efficient drawing of Android custom view

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-custom-view

I have an Android custom view that displays a grid of images downloaded from a server. The images are downloaded in the background, after an image has been downloaded, it is added to a list an view redraw is triggered.

So each time an image is downloaded, I draw a background and then the images in the list. This approach causes some flicker to appear. Plus I find it inefficient to draw all images just for one new image.

Is it possible to draw something in the view outside the OnDraw event? Thus I would draw only the newly downloaded image, instead of the whole list.
With Windows Forms I can do this outside the Paint event:

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics(); // this being a Control (<=> View), Graphics <=> Canvas
g.DrawSomething()
g.Dispose()
```

Is something similar available in Android or my approach is incorrect?

Comment: you should consider using a recycler view with grid layout manager, no need to write a custom view for such use cases

Comment: You can look at the [SurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) class, and refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544092/how-to-draw-a-bitmap-to-a-surfaceview).

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT I ended up using the SurfaceView class. If you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView), if your drawing is frequent, this class should be considered, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544092/how-to-draw-a-bitmap-to-a-surfaceview) is how to draw the bitmap on the `SurfaceView`.